# Google Earth Engine - Error downloading cloudfree Sentinel image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I got the following error message after trying to import cloud-free Sentinel-2 imagery for a polygon area covering the entire Tiwi Islands, Australia.

> true-colour image: Layer error: internal error

```
// Filter to only include images intersecting Tiwi.

var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon({
  coords: [[
[129.90415998438357,-12.027354108834277], [131.63999982813357,-12.027354108834277],
[131.63999982813357,-11.101721188177093], [129.90415998438357,-11.101721188177093], 
[129.90415998438357,-12.027354108834277]]],
  geodesic: false
});

//  Define the image collection we are working with by writing this command
    var image = ee.Image(sent2

    // filter to get only images in the date range we are interested in
    .filterDate("2018-09-01", "2018-11-30")

    // sort the collection by a metadata property, in our case cloud cover is a very useful one
    .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT")

    // select the first image out of this collection - i.e. the most cloud free image in the date range
    .first());

    // print the image to the console.
    print("A Sentinel-2 scene:", image);

    // Define visualization parameters in a JavaScript dictionary for true colour rendering. Bands 4,3 and 2 needed for RGB.
    var trueColour = {
        bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
        min: 0,
        max: 3000
        };

  // Add the image to the map, using the visualization parameters.
  Map.addLayer(image, trueColour, "true-colour image");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a polygon of the study area, use it for filtering. Also, the island is too big for 1 single image:

[image]

But, you can mosaic the date of less cloud of the entire study area (in this case I use the above scene to extract the date):

```
//  Define the image collection we are working with by writing this command
    var image = ee.Image(sent2

    // filter to get only images in the date range we are interested in
    .filterDate("2018-09-07", "2018-09-08")

    // filter by polygon
    .filterBounds(polygon)

    // filter by orbit number
    .filterMetadata('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER','equals',31)

    // sort the collection by a metadata property, in our case cloud cover is a very useful one
    .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT")

    // select the first image out of this collection - i.e. the most cloud free image in the date range
    .mosaic());
```

[image]

Or apply a reducer (I suggest you `min` or `median`):

```
//  Define the image collection we are working with by writing this command
    var image = ee.ImageCollection(sent2

    // filter to get only images in the date range we are interested in
    .filterDate("2018-09-01", "2018-11-30")

    // filter by polygon
    .filterBounds(polygon)

    // filter by orbit number
    .filterMetadata('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER','equals',31)

    // sort the collection by a metadata property, in our case cloud cover is a very useful one
    .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT")

    // select the first image out of this collection - i.e. the most cloud free image in the date range
    .min());
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! that works well. Is it also possible to create a mosaic of all the images in the entire date range with <10% cloud cover for instance?

Comment: Yes, using `.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10)`

Comment: Also, how did you use the above scene to extract the date?